# Why is Laravel Eloquent generating SQL without quotation marks?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to run `sudo php artisan migrate db:seed` on my Laravel installation and getting the following error:

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                          
  Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `sponsor_phones` (`phone_number`, `type`, `is_primary`, `sponsor_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at  
  `) values (247-216-6255 x4356, Home, 1, 101, 2017-05-30 23:31:59, 2017-05-30 23:31:59))
```

It seems that the SQL Eloquent is creating for seeding lacks quotation marks where they are neede. Adding quotations in the right places (below) allows it to run.

```
insert into 
`sponsor_phones` 
(`phone_number`,
 `type`, 
 `is_primary`, 
 `sponsor_id`, 
 `updated_at`, 
 `created_at`
 ) 
  values 
  (
  '(732) 540-9730', 
  'Busi', 
  0,
  51, 
  '2017-05-27 21:53:44', 
  '2017-05-27 21:53:44');
```

I'm not sure what's causing this error, and searching for reasons why Eloquent is not adding quotations seems to be failing to produce any useful results.

I've got a [repository](https://github.com/GraniteCiyGearheads3244/SponsorTrackingSystem) up so that you can take a look (and because as an open source project it needs one anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the quotations. In your ModelFactory.php, in functions `getTypePhone`, `getTypeEmail` and `getTypeAddress` you are returning

```
return $faker->randomElements(array('Work', 'Cell', 'Home', "VoIP"));
```

`$faker->randomElements` returns an array. Instead, use `$faker->randomElement` to return a single element from the array.

```
return $faker->randomElement(array('Work', 'Cell', 'Home', "VoIP"));
```

Comment: Thank you! Easy to miss there. Sometimes a second set of eyes is all you need. Still need to figure out some other stuff in the model factory, but that error is taken care of at the very least.